# Personalizar datos Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Tengo un gráfico lineal que muestra un valor (eje X) y una fecha (eje Y) y, cuando pongo el mouse encima de uno de los puntos, me muestra el valor X de la fecha Y

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy buscando alguna forma de, a parte de mostrar los datos de los ejes X e Y, poder añadir alguna otra información. Como se trata de los gastos e ingresos de una empresa, me gustaría poder añadir el nombre de compradores, vendedores y el balance total, por ejemplo.

El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
// Grafico para IO
var ctx = document.getElementById('IOChart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: balanceDates,
        datasets: [{
            label: 'I/O',
            data: IOValues,
            backgroundColor: 'gainsboro',
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderColor: dotsColor,
            pointBorderColor: dotsColor,
            pointBackgroundColors: dotsColor
        }]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        mantainAspectRatio: false,
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: false,
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});


// Establecemos los colores de los puntos segun su valor
var dotsColor = []
for (var i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    if (dots[i] == 1) {
        dotsColor.push('green')
    } else {
        dotsColor.push('red')
    }
}
```

Los datos, que los obtengo directamente de la Base de Datos, los paso a variables de JS. Cabe decir que uso Django (2.2), para no dejar dudas.

```
<script>
    var balanceValues = {{ balance|safe }}
    var IOValues = {{ IO|safe }}
    var balanceDates = {{ balanceDates|safe }}
    var dots = {{ IODots|safe }}
</script>
```

Y el canvas ( no tiene mucho misterio ):

```
<canvas id="IOChart" class="d-none" width="1200" height="575"></canvas>
```